# .is() - use AND instead of OR condition

Tags: jquery

At the moment, the result of `.is()` will return true if ANY (**OR**) of the conditions are `true`, how do I make it use **AND** instead, i.e. only return `true` if ALL conditions are met?

```
if ($('#search-form #valid_only').is(':checked, :enabled')) {

}
```

Comment: what are the conditions

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I only have two conditions at the moment, but suppose I have 10, how would the best approach be without using multiple `&&` operators?

Comment: `if ($('#valid_only').is(':checked:enabled')) {

}`

Comment: You can also try `if ($('#valid_only:checked:enabled').length) `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That comma in your selector is equivalent to an OR.

Use both conditions without a comma separating them inside **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**

```
if ($('#search-form #valid_only').is(':checked:enabled') { // checked and enabled
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to check for `:checked`, `:enabled` and having a class name `foo`, you can do `.foo:checked:enabled`

Answer (score 2):

You can just combine your selectors:

```
if ($('#search-form #valid-only').is(':checked:enabled')) {
}
```